# CURL with application/json content-type — Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net, content-type

Trying to send CURL to .NET REST api that I've builded with this payload: 
Request={"a":"b"} . I need the content type to be application/json.

- with Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, everything work.
- with Content-Type: application/json, I got an error

> "Message": "An error has occurred.", "ExceptionMessage": "Object
>   reference not set to an instance of an object.",
>   "ExceptionType": "System.NullReferenceException",

Please Help :(

```
public class mdSparkPostWHEvent
{
    public string Request { get; set; }
}

[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SparkPostWHEvent([FromBody] mdSparkPostWHEvent Inputs)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage()
    { 
        Content = new StringContent(SQLFunctions.SQLStoreProcedure("sDV04_WebRequestTest", Inputs, true) ,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this as the payload for Content-Type: application/json:

```
{"Inputs":{"Request":"b"}}
```

Comment: almost  Payload : {"Request":"a"} work since the input parameter is @Request